# How to redirect if I receive 404 error using axios?

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, axios, redux-thunk

I want to redirect if I receive 404 error except one route - /api/profile.

I use axios and I'm not sure if I can use interceptors for this case.

Can I do something like this?

```
axios.interceptors.response.use( ( response ) => {
    return response;
}, ( error ) => {
    if ( error.response.status === 404 && error.config.url !== '/api/profile' ) {
        history.push( '/not-found' ); 
        return Promise.reject( error );
    }   
    return Promise.reject( error );
});
```

or should I stick to this:

```
axios.get( '/api/something' ).then( ( res ) => {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_SOMETHING,
        payload: res.data
    });
}).catch( ( err ) => {
    if ( err.response.status == 404 ) {
        history.push( '/not-found' );
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: `windows.location.href` or `windows.location.replace` ? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: Interceptors is used to get some additional details from response. If you just want to handle the error your 2nd approach is fine.. check https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors. Are you facing any problem?